# Measure length of text for a label

Tags: wpf, label, font-family

I'm trying to dynamically shorten a label based on available space.  I use FormattedText to determine the length of the candidate string

```
formattedText = new FormattedText(candidateString, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, FontSize = fontSize, Brushes.Black);
```

I should be able to retrieve the Typeface from the Label containing the text; however I keep running into roadblocks:

- Label contains FontFamily but not Typeface.
- I can't create a new Typeface from FontFamily since I can't get a single FontFamily name
  `Typeface t = new Typeface(theLabel.FontFamily.FamilyNames.?, theLabel.FontStyle, theLabel.FontSize, theLabel.FontStretch);`

This seems like it ought to be simple: I want the typeface used in THAT label (pointing to screen).  How can a create a Typeface for use in measuring my string length?  Is there a simpler way to accomplish this?  What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered to use TextBlock and TextTrimming property instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work?

```
Typeface t = new Typeface(theLabel.FontFamily,theLabel.FontStyle,theLabel.FontWeight,theLabel.FontStretch, new FontFamily("Arial"));
```

or you can experiment with

```
theLabel.FontFamily.GetTypefaces();
```

Comment: That does work; and the fallback font (last parameter) is optional, so it doesn't need any hard-coded values.  Thanks.